# How to properly use Qt Designer together with Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to learn to make Desktop Applications using Qt Creator and qtpy, but my result does not look like expected. I created this simple thing in Qt Designer (and expected the result to look similar):

[image]

By saving that, I got a file mainwindow.ui in the a directory 'ui' located in my Python project directory. By running the following skript once, i got a mainwindow.py file:

```
from qtpy import uic

uic.compileUiDir("ui")
```

Next I ran my main program:

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets
from ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

ui_window = Ui_MainWindow()
ui_window.setupUi(window)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But the result does not look as exspected. All the Widgets seem to be too small and the content has been cutten off:

[image]

How can I get the result to look like in Qt Creator?

I use Pycharm Community 2020.2 with a virtual environment
The following Python packages are installed:
PyQt5 v 5.15.0
PyQt5-sip v 12.8.0
QtPy v 1.9.0
I use Qt Creator 4.11.2

Maybe it helps to provide the details of the files

mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>398</width>
    <height>673</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>113</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>100</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>RadioButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>87</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>CheckBox</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>398</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

mainwindow.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui\mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(398, 249)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 60, 100, 20))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralWidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 130, 87, 20))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 398, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experiencing is *exactly* the reason for which layout managers should be *always* preferred, instead of using fixed geometries.

A partial solution to your specific issue is to use [`adjustSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize) on all widgets:

```
ui_window.checkBox.adjustSize()
ui_window.pushButton.adjustSize()
ui_window.radioButton.adjustSize()
```

In this way all widgets will adjust their geometry ensuring that they will be able to show all their contents.

But, obviously, this is not a very good solution, and that's not only because you might have dozens of widgets.

The problem with fixed geometries is that what you see in your computer (or even in Designer) will almost *never* be the same on different computers. That might depend on lots of factors, including:

- system configuration
- default font and font size
- screen resolution *and* DPI
- user customization

In your case, the inconsistency comes from how Designer "draws" widgets using *its* default style (note that you should be able to preview your GUI in different styles from the "Form" menu) and what actually happens when you actually run the program from python, using the *system* default style.

Using layout managers allows for management and optimization of available space, ensuring that all widgets are correctly displayed and use as much space as possible or required.

The situations in which fixed geometries are valid are very rare, and if you're actually needing them it's only because you *really* know why and how to deal with them.

For the remaining 99.9% of situations, the *actual* solution is to use layout managers.
Right click on an empty point of the interface, open the "Lay out..." submenu, and select one of the available layouts. If you need to put widgets in more "specific" positions, consider using a grid layout and horizontal/vertical spacers (drag them from the top of the widget box).